# Problemas com setuid

Tags: android, c, linux, file-permission

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que altera o uid do meu processo para 0 permitindo que eu possa iniciar outros programs como root.

```
mysu.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    int myuid = getuid();
    if (setuid(0))
    {
        printf("su: permission deniedd\n");
        return 1;
    }

    system("ls /data/data");
    setuid(myuid);

    return 0;
}
```

Logo após compilo:

```
gcc mysu.c -o mysu
```

Muda o owner para root:

```
su
chown root:root mysu
chmod 6755 mysu
exit
```

Porém ao executá-lo a function setuid retorna um valor diferente de 0 indicando que não foi possível mudar o uid, mas ao executá-lo como root o código funciona sem problemas. Vi algumas perguntas semelhantes porém não consegui resolver esse problema.

Comment: Isso tem Android como alvo?

Comment: Sim, esse programa é para android e linux